# How to programmatically set backgroundTint of FloatingActionButton with ColorStateList?

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button

Programmatically setting my `FloatingActionButton`'s `backgroundTint` via `setBackgroundTintList` method does not work, but setting it via XML `app:backgroundTint` tag does work - why is that?

The fab_background_color.xml color list state is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:color="#654321"/>

    <item android:color="#123456"/>

</selector>
```

My activity layout is:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and activity code:

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_position_sample);

        final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.test);

        // Uncomment to test - this does NOT work however.
        //fab.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.fab_background_color));

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (fab.isSelected())
                    fab.setSelected(false);
                else
                    fab.setSelected(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If I add:

`fab.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.fab_background_color));`

or:

`fab.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.fab_background_color));`

To the activity code before setting up the click listener, nothing happens.

If I add:

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_background_color"
```

To the activity layout code for the FloatingActionButton, I get the expected behavior.

Any thoughts? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When does the programmatical method doesnt work? In clicked state?

Comment: When the button is set to be selected (done in my activity code), the color does not update.  It stays in the default color.

Comment: Set to be selected? Are you adding `setBackgroundTintList()` inside `onClickListener()` to put it simple?

Comment: See my code - I am setting the FAB to be selected (if it's not already selected).

The ColorStateList should handle choosing the right color automatically, that's the whole point of the Color state.  Of course I can do this individually but that is not the point - it's supposed to work based on the selected state of the view, but only does so when setup via XML.

Comment: Wrote this up as an Android issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved as of Android Support Library 25.1.0

See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227428

Answer (score 27):

use this:

```
fab.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(), R.color.purple_200));
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference in behavior unfortunately.  Thanks though.

Comment: requires api 21+

Answer (score 6):

Since `setBackgroundTintList` is only supported in API 21+ you can use ViewCompat.

```java
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(
    fab, 
    ContextCompat.getColorStateList(
        getApplicationContext(),
        R.color.purple_200
    )
);
```